# Saving vector art using Illustrator with the intent to sell artwork to people who work with various vector software and versions of Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, export, cs5, save

I have been making vector art recently and am looking into hopefully selling it either on existing websites or maybe creating my own, the website in a way would also be a portfolio and it would give me more experience in making websites and UI elements. If I were to make my own website there would be various Png versions (probably png 24) of the art at different resolutions and then a vector version.

My main question is how to save my existing vector art I have made (in Illustrator CS5) and make it available to anyone who hopefully buys it and downloads it. I was thinking I can't just let them download them the AI file because not everyone has Illustrator and if they do not everyone has the CS5 version and would a CS5 document even open in CS4 and earlier or even CS6?

When saving my existing artwork should I go back to EPS10, which is what some of the research I have done on the topic suggests and what is the process of saving as EPS10 and what are the restriction in doing so or should I just stick to illustrator and pick a version e.g. CS2 as the minimum requirement to open the art?

Comment: A few issues in mind is what are you willing to allow to be edited?  Some people offer a single layer `.eps` file which is the norm, as already stated, with no layer editing options.  Some people sell the vectors in a packaged deal which include `.ai`, `.cdr`, and `.pdf`.  I would base the file format on what you feel best offering. Personally I would create your own eCommerce site, allow `.eps` single layer and offer a packaged, file formats with layer options, for a price increase.

Comment: Yeah, some give  eps plus the final .ai (or .cdr for Corel) that they used to make it. I wouldn't personally, but that's just me (my working files are my own personal brand of controlled chaos, would feel too much like someone looking over my shoulder watching me work...), and you could certainly justify charging extra. Also, there are loads of stock vector sites and stock photo sites that also do vector that would host your work in return for a percentage on each sale. I've never used them so I don't know if they're worth it or not, but they might be the first place would-be customers look

Comment: I would not even attempt to do this on your own. There's no way any site you build will compete with sites already out there. Even if you aren't "competing" no one is going to a site for a single artist when they can hit a stock site with hundreds of artists. I would think your best option is to start submitting to already existing sites who sell vector artwork. Let them handle billing, collections, and monitoring. If you're good, your stuff will sell and the royalties can add up quickly in spite of only being a percentage of sales.

Comment: Once you start trying to deal with pricing, customer issues, illegal use of images, etc.. the royalty structures make far more sense. I certainly wouldn't want to waste my time on all the clerical issues you must attend to. That being posted, the most popular site for this stuff is horrible for artists and I wouldn't recommend that site. (Note, while I have sold in the past, I currently don't sell vectors on any site. So I have experience in the past, but nothing current)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**eps** is the standard, and the process is as simple as choosing eps from the Save As menu. It's been the standard for this sort of thing (final asset delivery) for longer than I've been in the industry, is understood by basically all vector design software, and is very similar to Illustrator's native format (the original post script format eps is based on was an adobe creation, used in PDFs and in AI files).

Just don't expect artboards or anything else requiring illustrator-specific meta data to come out the same. The product - the core artwork - however, should be fine. You should make sure that anything depending on an Illustrator feature still works when expanded - but when you're producing for all versions and all vector software, this should be part of your workflow anyway.

---

In theory, you could use **SVG** as a nice modern standard that can also be displayed in browsers. Unfortunately, the way Illustrator handles SVG files is messy and non-standard, and they can't realistically replace PNG on your site as internet explorer versions before 9 (still a large % of internet users) don't understand them. But they might replace eps as the standard one day.

---

**Tip:** if selling vector artwork, make sure that there aren't any paths you think are closed that are actually left open. It's an easy, common mistake (especially if you've been drawing freehand with the pencil tool), and can cause artwork to be rejected or customers to complain - people buy vectors to work with them (generally speaking), and iunexpected open paths make them harder to work with. There are scripts that help if you have trouble. Here's an article from a stock site with more info - http://www.istockphoto.com/article_view.php?ID=578 - they recommend the free [select menu plugin from Graffix](http://rj-graffix.com/software/plugins.html#SelectMenu)